# Rails - Prevent Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, browser

Is there a way to prevent Internet Explorer from accessing the web application?

In fact, I wouldn't mind displaying a static page informing them to download Firefox. I want to stop supporting IE, but I'm not sure the best approach.

Comment: you need to give them a degraded user experience rather than nothing, you should also display a notice to tell them that they are using an unsupported browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are basically three ways to detect the browser.

1. [Check the user agent](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html). This method is unreliable and generally should
   not be used, although there are some cases where it might be okay.
2. [Check javascript object support](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html). This is usually done
   when executing javascript code and is a good thing to do in order to
   make sure objects exist before you try to use them. There are some
   objects that might be exclusively defined in IE, but there is
   a chance that some other browser will have the object defined as
   well.
3. [Use conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). This is the route I would use with since
   you are looking specifically for IE (conditional comments only apply
   to IE). This option will also give you the ability to target certain
   versions of IE reliably.

Here is an example that would redirect if the browser is IE <= 7.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script>
window.location = 'download-firefox.html';
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is to support any browser.

Design for the best possible browser and give the rest a workable alternative. It is fine to disable alot of css and javascript for IE6 users for example. But to make it non accessible all together seems a bit harsh.

For example, you could serve IE6 users this stylesheet

http://code.google.com/p/universal-ie6-css/

Also get something like Google Analytics to check and see which % of visits to your site each browser has. This is a decent way to determine how much time you should invest in making your site work for different browsers, their versions and OS

Comment: While I agree with you to a point, more specifically IE is a thorn in the side, and losing popularity due to it's in ability to follow the w3c standards. IE 10, and it still has some problems with: javascript, SVG (sort fixed), & websockets (sorta working). All essential to a functional (not decorative) business webapp. This link(http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) shows that in the year of 2013, IE has lost almost about 10% of it's share, moving to chrome. +80% use chrome/firefox, %12 -> IE. I'm not hurt being "harsh" to IE. Contrary, I'm protecting users & my product.

Comment: there are cases where you dont want to support all browsers, e.g when building a private website and not wanting to deal with IE

Comment: Agreed with the answer, and I appreciate the time taken to write it - but it actually does not answer the original question